# Python Pandas: creating a dataframe using a function for one of the fields

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

I am trying to create a dataframe where one of the fields is calculated using a function.  To do this I use the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

def didSurvive(sex):
    return int(sex == "female")


titanic_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
submission = pd.DataFrame({
    "PassengerId": titanic_df["PassengerId"],
    "Survived": didSurvive(titanic_df["Sex"])
})
submission.to_csv('titanic-predictions.csv', index=False)
```

when I run this code I get the following error:

> D:\Documents\kaggle\titanic>python predictor.py
>   File "predictor.py", line 3
>   def didSurvive() {
>   ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>   D:\Documents\kaggle\titanic>python predictor.py
>   D:\Documents\kaggle\titanic>python predictor.py
>   D:\Documents\kaggle\titanic>python predictor.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "predictor.py", line 10, in 
>   "Survived": didSurvive(titanic_df["Sex"])
>   File "predictor.py", line 4, in didSurvive
>   return int(sex == "female")
>   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 92,
>   in wrapper
>   "{0}".format(str(converter)))
>   TypeError: cannot convert the series to 
>   D:\Documents\kaggle\titanic>

I think what is happening is I'm trying to run the int() on a series of booleans instead of an individual boolean.  How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

To convert the data type of a Series, you can use `astype()` function, this should work:

```
def didSurvive(sex):
    return (sex == "female").astype(int)
```

Comment: Nice that worked.... What was wrong with using int() and why does .astype() work?

Comment: As you have noticed, `int()` function takes a number or string and converts it to an integer. It is a base python function and doesn't take Series object as parameter. `astype()` is pandas built in function for type conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also reformat data during the import from csv file

```
titanic_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", converters={'Sex':didSurvive})
submission = pd.DataFrame(titanic_df, columns=['PassengerId', 'Sex'])
```

Comment: Is there any advantage or disadvantage to using this method rather than calling a function when creating a data frame like how psidom and I are doing it?